# Eliminate duplicate flow run in power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, microsoft-flow, duplicate

I am facing unbearable problem with the flow in power automate. Previously my flow worked perfectly without any problem. But recently, all of my flows keep running twice every time after the trigger is executed. It results in duplicate flow running for each time when I run the flow.
You can see details here in the images below: [image]

Noted that when I tested the flow using testing function in power automate, the flow only runs one time as expected. But in real situation, when I modified the item, it keeps running twice.
I do not have any  infinite trigger loop with apply to each.

Here is the flow configuration: [image]

Have anybody faced this strange issue before? Any suggestions on what I should do to fix it are deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is the trigger of flow? Are you using "update item" action for same list in the flow? Can you add screenshot of your flow if possible?

Comment: No. I did not use the update item within the flow. I only compose the email and name of person to string to avoid the unnecessary loop of apply to each and get the attachment. The detail of my flow was just added as well. Please take a look

Comment: @Bella Can you try re-creating the trigger to see if it is the same outcome?

Comment: As you said, you didn't make any modifications and this happened suddenly? Try running in browser private mode? Or can you provide more details about the flow?

Comment: @thebernardlim, Yes I did recreate the flow. But it didn't help at all. The flow kept running twice for every single trigger> and now it happened for all of my flows, which terribly unacceptable

Comment: @AmyJiang_MSFT, No the issue still remains the same. When I tried to applied Get changes for an item or a file (properties only), I realized that when the flow running twice, the since version number and until version number hold distance of 1. For example, if the since version number of my flow is 3 then the until version number is 4. It is the same for the duplicate running of my flow. But when the flow only runs one time, the distance between since version number and until version number is 2. For example, the since version number 3 then the until version number is 5.